# Autorization using bearer token failing

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, post, bearer-token

Friends

I am accessing an API using bearer token authorization and getting HTTP status 401.

The problematic code is Dart code (in a Flutter app). I have Swift code that accesses the same API so I can check the headers I am passing.

The Dart code:

```dart
  var client = http.Client();
  var url = Uri.https(<site>, <path>);
  Map<String, String> body = {
     <Hash entries to define request>
  };
  var headers = <String, String>{
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept" : "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer <Hex token>",
  };
  var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
```

`http` is from: `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

The hex token is taken from a successful login.  It is the same as I see after a successful login with the Swift app.

The "Accept" and "Content-Type" are also the same as the Swift app.

In  `result` the `statusCode` is 401 and `reasonPhrase` is "Unauthorized"

The Swift app is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This was not the problem I thought.

The Authorization header is ignored by the server and it does some cookie magic to authorise.

In Swift the cookies were set without my intervention.  So I never understood that the Bearer.... authorization was ignored.